# Can anyone see the issue with my code (cannot convert int to boolean) Processing

Tags: loops, rotation, processing

I am trying to create the reverse of this. Only 1 visible circle at a time.

http://www.rpdms.com/satillusion/saturation%20illusionc.gif

I have adapted my code

```
int nbr_circles = 2;
void setup() {
size(600, 600);
smooth();
background(255);
}

void draw() {
background(255);
float cx = width/2.0;
float cy = height/2.0;
fill(0);
//float x, y; //
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_circles; i++)
{
float angle = i * TWO_PI / nbr_circles;
float x = cx + 110.0 * cos(angle);
float y = cy + 110.0 * sin(angle);
ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
}
}

void mousePressed() {

if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
if (nbr_circles < 20)
nbr_circles = nbr_circles + 1;

} else if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
if (nbr_circles > 2)
nbr_circles = nbr_circles - 1;

}
}
```

To this

```
int nbr_circles = 1;
void setup() {    
  size(600, 600);
  smooth();
  background(255);
} 

void draw() { 
  float cx = width/2.0;
  float cy = height/2.0;
  fill(0);
  //float x, y; //
  for (int i = 0; i < nbr_circles; i++)
  {  
    float angle = i * TWO_PI / nbr_circles;
    float x = cx + 110.0 * cos(angle);                
    float y = cy + 110.0 * sin(angle);                
    ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i = nbr_circles; i++)
  {
    translate (width/2.0, height/2.0);
    rotate (radians());
  }
}
```

But get an error saying 'cannot convert int to boolean" the second for loop.

I'm sure that that's not the only mistake.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is equality check. Also, shouldn't you be checking as `i <= nbr_circles`?

Comment: @shree.pat18

I understand far less than you give me credit for!

I only began learning 2 days ago. What do you mean? I know the difference between = and == and <=  (thanks to you).

Comment: Well your second loop should terminate once i exceeds the number of circles requirs. That is what the less than or equal to condition will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He means in the line `for (int i = 0; i = nbr_circles; i++)` the `=` makes no sense, it should be a condition to stop the loop, the `=` makes an assignment, which makes no sense in this case. It could be `==` but then there is no point in having the loop… Probably you want a `<` instead. The for loop goes like:

```
      int x = 0                        x < 10                 x = x+1
```

for(this variable initialized to this number; while that var meets this condition; do this to that var){}

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to accomplish correctly, I don't think you even need that second for loop. With the first loop you've got all the calculations for the circle positions, so now you just need to figure out how to display only one at a time, correct?

Your comment above indicates that you're just starting out with Processing (and possibly programming in general) so forgive me if I overexplain things you already know.

Here's what I would do: instead of calculating the positions of all the circles on each frame in the draw() function, you can calculate them once in setup() and store the positions in an array. There's a handy object in Processing, the PVector class, that can be used to easily store these positions as x and y values. So at the top of your code, right after the variable declaration for nbr_circles, you can declare an array of PVectors that will store all of the circle positions, like so:

```
PVector[] circles = new PVector[nbr_circles];
```

Then you can move the code that calculates the circle positions into setup(), and instead of displaying the circles at the calculated points, you would store the values in the array instead:

```
void setup() {    
    size(600, 600);
    smooth();
    background(255);

    float cx = width/2.0;
    float cy = height/2.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nbr_circles; i++)
    {  
        float angle = i * TWO_PI / nbr_circles;
        float x = cx + 110.0 * cos(angle);                
        float y = cy + 110.0 * sin(angle);                
        circles[i] = new PVector(x, y);
    }
}
```

Now that we've got all the circle positions stored, if we wanted to display them all at once, we could loop through the array in the draw() function and display a circle for each set of coordinates:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbr_circles; i++) {
    ellipse(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, 20, 20);
}
```

But what we really want to do is display one circle each time the draw() function is called. Instead of using the for loop to go through every array element each time, we need to pick just one, and we want that one to be the one that comes after the element shown in the last frame. We can declare a counter variable at the top that we can use to keep track of which array element should be displayed:

```
int counter = 0;
```

In the draw() function, we can increment the counter each time and use that value as the array index. Of course, once the counter variable becomes larger than the number of elements in the array we'll need to set it back to 0. The modulo operator (%) can help us out here, it basically returns the remainder of dividing two numbers. Now we can simply increase the counter variable by one each time through (using the increment operator, ++), and use the modulo operator to always get a number from 0 to (nbr_circles - 1). Here's my draw() function:

```
void draw() { 
    background(255);
    fill(0);

    int i = counter % nbr_circles;
    ellipse(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, 20, 20);
    counter++;
}
```

You'll notice that the circles go around the loop pretty fast; this is because the default frame rate (the number of times the draw() function is called each second) is I believe 30. Fortunately, there's a simple function you can call somewhere inside the setup() function that will set the frame rate to whatever you want. If you want to slow things down, try 5 frames per second:

```
frameRate(5);
```

Put this all together, and you should have it!